# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0? see detail in output1111

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, index-error

```
#count the number of fake and real videos
def number_of_real_and_fake_videos(data_list):
    header_list = ["file","label"]
    lab = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Gobal_metadata.csv',names=header_list)
    fake = 0
    real = 0
    for i in data_list:
    temp_video = i.split('/')[-1]
    label = lab.iloc[(labels.loc[labels["file"] == temp_video].index.values[0]),1]
    if(label == 'FAKE'):
        fake+=1
    if(label == 'REAL'):
        real+=1
    return real,fake
```

```
# load the labels and video in data loader
import random
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

header_list = ["file","label"]
labels = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Gobal_metadata.csv',names=header_list)
#print(labels)
train_videos = video_files[:int(0.8*len(video_files))]
valid_videos = video_files[int(0.8*len(video_files)):]
print("train : " , len(train_videos))
print("test : " , len(valid_videos))
# train_videos,valid_videos = train_test_split(data,test_size = 0.2)
# print(train_videos)

print("TRAIN: ", "Real:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(train_videos)[0]," Fake:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(train_videos)[1])
print("TEST: ", "Real:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(valid_videos)[0]," Fake:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(valid_videos)[1])


im_size = 112
mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
                                        transforms.ToPILImage(),
                                        transforms.Resize((im_size,im_size)),
                                        transforms.ToTensor(),
                                        transforms.Normalize(mean,std)])

test_transforms = transforms.Compose([
                                        transforms.ToPILImage(),
                                        transforms.Resize((im_size,im_size)),
                                        transforms.ToTensor(),
                                        transforms.Normalize(mean,std)])
train_data = video_dataset(train_videos,labels,sequence_length = 10,transform = train_transforms)
#print(train_data)
val_data = video_dataset(valid_videos,labels,sequence_length = 10,transform = train_transforms)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data,batch_size = 4,shuffle = True,num_workers = 2)
valid_loader = DataLoader(val_data,batch_size = 4,shuffle = True,num_workers = 2)
image,label = train_data[0]
im_plot(image[0,:,:,:])
```

Output:

```
train :  8720
test :  2180
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-7ad703495b44> in <module>()
     14 # print(train_videos)
     15 
---> 16 print("TRAIN: ", "Real:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(train_videos)[0]," Fake:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(train_videos)[1])
     17 print("TEST: ", "Real:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(valid_videos)[0]," Fake:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(valid_videos)[1])
     18 

<ipython-input-29-8723d4941fd5> in number_of_real_and_fake_videos(data_list)
      7   for i in data_list:
      8     temp_video = i.split('/')[-1]
----> 9     label = lab.iloc[(labels.loc[labels["file"] == temp_video].index.values[0]),1]
     10     if(label == 'FAKE'):
     11       fake+=1

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: You should explain more about your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 lines of code are accessing a list index that may not exist

```
print("TRAIN: ", "Real:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(train_videos)[0]," Fake:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(train_videos)[1])
print("TEST: ", "Real:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(valid_videos)[0]," Fake:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(valid_videos)[1])
```

Maybe try a safer alternative

```
if len(number_of_real_and_fake_videos(train_videos)) > 1:
    print("TRAIN: ", "Real:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(train_videos)[0]," Fake:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(train_videos)[1])
```

Same for the other one

```
if len(number_of_real_and_fake_videos(valid_videos)) > 1:
    print("TEST: ", "Real:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(valid_videos)[0]," Fake:",number_of_real_and_fake_videos(valid_videos)[1])
```

Regarding why it happens, we would need the data, etc. But this a good starting point to find out what's causing the issue, trying printing the data, etc.

Comment: I change those two line in my code but the error dose not fixed.

Comment: Sorry got the second one wrong, try again. Anyways that will only fix the crashing program but not the real issue there which is the data is not what you're expecting.

Comment: How can I solve it, This error also happened to train the model.

Comment: Need to look at the data etc, need to learn how to debug it yourself. I fixed the issue you had that was crashing the program though :)